# Returning to the same tab data

Tags: ios, tabs

I m working with a project in ios. In that i m using 3tabs and  each tab is having diffrent sub tabs. In the sub-tabs  there are image views and the buttons. The image view will only appair when i click the tab type and its sub tab type. On the click of the button of the sub tabs my app navigate to new view controller. And on the new view controller i am using the back button to navigate back to the view where tabs and data is there. On the Back button's click when i reach back to the first view i have to select the tabs again to review the data.
 Is there any possible way to reach back to the same tab from where we navigate to the second view controller??
 Your help will be much appriciable.

Comment: if you use a `UINavigationController` object on every tab then the task is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @staticVoidMan thanx buddy it is working...... but when i reach back to previous vew  the navigation bar appears, but i dnt want that. I want to keep it hidden...

Comment: in that case, use `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];` in the `viewDidLoad` or `init` method of the `viewController` where you don't want to display the `navigationBar`

Comment: but when i return back from second view controller to first it will not call the viewdidload function, but it will upload the previous load. In that case how can we use this [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; .

Comment: put the code in the `-viewWillAppear` then (_but the first suggestion should technically work because the `viewDidLoad` will basically load the `viewController` without the `navigationBar` in the first place and so when you return, the `navigationBar` should still be hidden for that `viewController`_)

Comment: no it is appearing when i return back to the view..